# Course of action based on Cypress assertions

Tags: css-selectors, cypress, assert, assertion

I have a question: What happens if I need to create a **course of action** based on an assert in Cypress? Suppose that when entering a certain page, there is a pop-up window that is visible randomly; sometimes it appears and sometimes it doesn't. So, I need to click the "OK" button on that popup when it appears just to make it go away. How can I make sure that the test does not fail on occasions when that window does not appear? The test fails since it does not find the corresponding element to the "Accept" button. How do I make it ignore that action when the window doesn't appear? Thank you in advance.

```
 I tryed with something like this, but it doesn't work:

    if(cy.get('#pop-up-window-1').should('exist')){
      cy.get('#btn-accept').click()
    }else{
      nothing
    }
```

Comment: Surely there is something that can suppress the pop from displaying. Have you checked for cookies created by the pop up?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Check the length and if its greater than 0, then element is present, if not then element is not present.

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('#pop-up-window-1').length > 0) {
    //pop up is present
    cy.get('#btn-accept').click()
  } else {
    cy.log('Pop Up not present. Moving on..')
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi Alapan, thanks for anwering!! Should I replace 'body' for something else or is that a kind of varible created during the execution?

Comment: `$body` is the variable, you can write anything in place of that. `cy.get('body')` will stay as is, because we are making sure that first, the body is present in the dom and then we are searching the element.

Comment: I can't implement this solution yet because there is an issue related to the locators in the middle (I put '#pop-up-window-1' just in order to simplify the question but this is not the real one) but I think this approach is the way to solve it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional testing can give you a flaky test.

If you test for the presence of the popup with `if ($body.find('#pop-up-window-1').length)` the timing may be off, and sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

That's particularly true if the modal uses animation to open.

One option is to wait for a suitable period before checking

```js
cy.wait(3000)
cy.get('body').then($body => {
  if ($body.find('#pop-up-window-1').length) {
    cy.get('#btn-accept').click()
  }
})
```